# DOM Exception When trying to change Metadata on S3 using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to update the content-type metadata on S3 using the AWS SDK for Javascript with the `copyObject` function.

The code:

```
var s3Client = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: "xxxx",
  secretAccessKey: "xxxxxx"
});

var params = {
  Bucket: "shareimg-temp.test.com", // required
  CopySource: encodeURI('userimg-temp.test.com/uploads/' + fileName),
  Key: 'uploads/' + fileName, // required
  ACL: 'private', // tried without but didn't help
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  MetadataDirective: 'REPLACE'
};
```

s3Client.copyObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else
        console.log(data); // successful response
});

**Error:**

I am getting the following exception error from aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc10.min.js:

```
InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

In the bucket uploads folder I do have the filename specified in the fileName. I gave full permissions (temporary just for debugging purposes).

My goal is to change the content-type to `image/jpeg`  as when I upload it is updates with `binary/octet-stream` instead.

Spent hours on this and any help will be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the same error message albeit with a AWS DynamoDB.